# Dynamic Dropdown onselect

Tags: php, javascript

What I am trying to do is when a item is selected from my dropdown menu, it would make a input box  appear with the description selected on the dropdown menu, so that it can be edited and updated back into the database,

I am unsure how to handle the javascript:

**Dropdown Code:**

```
<select name="captionSelect" id="captionSelect">
    <?php foreach ($get_images as $image){
        echo '<option value="'.$image['id'].'">'.$image['description'].'</option>';
    };
    ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input has id 'captionInput', here's a sample code to show the input with dropdown's selected value:

```
$('#captionSelect').change(function(){
    $('#captionInput').val($("#captionSelect option:selected").text()).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank You,  This works fine but in my code the value is the ID and the value text is what I am wanting to show in the text box is this possible?

Comment: This code will show the description. If you want value, then use `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Add an onchange event to the select which calls a function.  That function can either update another element directly OR do an ajax call to grab the description on the fly.

Comment: Yes I understand that but what I do not understand is the correct way to to this can you link to an example?